# How to add a lightbox effect in Magento product image switcher?

Tags: jquery, magento, thickbox

I recently bumped into an article from [inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-product-images-switcher/)

It changes the default way on how magento displays *more view thumbnails*.. It's easy to integrate but I want a more extended functionality which is when the Main picture (the large image) is clicked, it will display the image currently in the main picture in a lightbox. Here's the code of my **media.phtml**...

I have integrated a thickbox in my magento just by using class="thickbox" in an  tag..

```
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_gallery = $this->getGalleryImages();

    $_resize = 350;
?>

<style type="text/css">
    .product-img-box .more-views li.slide-current a{ border:2px solid #aaa; }
    .product-img-box .product-image-zoom img { cursor: pointer; }
    #slide-loader{ visibility:hidden; position:absolute; top:auto; left:auto; right:2px; bottom:2px; width: 25px; height: 25px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function slide(url,num,gallery){
    if (typeof slide.loading == 'undefined') slide.loading = false;
    if(slide.loading) return false;

    var loader = new Image();
    $(loader).observe('load', function(){

        $('slide-loader').setStyle({'visibility':'hidden'});

        $$('div.more-views li').each(function(el,i){
            (i==num) ? el.addClassName('slide-current') : el.removeClassName('slide-current');
        });

        var dummy = new Element('img', { src: url }).setOpacity(0);
        new Insertion.After('image', dummy);
        new Effect.Opacity(dummy, { duration:.5, from:0, to:1.0 });
        new Effect.Opacity($('image'), { duration:.5, from:1.0, to:0, 
             afterFinish: function(){
                $('image').writeAttribute('src',url).setOpacity(1).observe('click',function(e){
                    Event.stop(e);
                    popWin(gallery, 'gallery', 'width=300,height=300,left=50,top=50,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); 
                    return false;

                 })
                dummy.remove();
                slide.loading = false;
             }
        });
    });

    $('slide-loader').setStyle({'visibility':'visible'});
    loader.src=url;

    slide.loading = true;
return false;
}
</script>


<p class="product-image-zoom">
    <?php
        $_img = '<a class="thickbox" href="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'"><img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" /></a>';
        echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image')
    ?>
    <img id="slide-loader" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/lightbox/loading.gif') ?>" />
</p>
<!-- <p class="a-center" id="track_hint"><?php echo $this->__('Click on above image to view full picture') ?></p> -->

<?php if (count($_gallery) > 0): ?>
<div class="more-views">
    <h4><?php echo $this->__('More Views') ?></h4>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($_gallery as $_image): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>" onclick="slide('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()) ?>',<?php echo ($s = isset($s) ? ++$s : 0) ?>,'<?php echo $this->getGalleryUrl($_image) ?>'); return false;"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(65); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks and more power!

Comment: Sorry, what is the question here? In what way does this not work for you as specified?

Comment: Sorry for being vague.. What I would like to ask is how to extend the functionality which is when the Main picture (the large image) is clicked, it will display the image currently in the main picture in a lightbox..

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you accomplished this? We are looking for the exact same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use one of the many lightbox modules already available in connect?

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/TemplatesMaster/extension/1487/magento-easy-lightbox/

Comment: hi.. i tried using this but the client wants her obsolete thickbox lightbox.. thanks anyway.. already solved this one after several days.. :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Lightboxes(Fancybox, pirobox & lightbox clone) is one the best jQuery lightbox extension for magento. Recently it has been updated with lots of new features. 
Give a try:
http://www.magepsycho.com/jquery-lightbox-es.html